# wso2 admin service

Tags: wso2

Where can I find a list of the carbon admin services?

For example I know about the AuthenticationAdmin service however I would like to check what other services there are and check their wsdls. I couldn't find any in the documentation, where can I find those.

The only information I could get hold on was http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/03/invoking-wso2-carbon-admin-services.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can start the Carbon server with -DosgiConsole option to go to the osgi console. If you type help in the console, you will get all the commands available.

listAdminServices command will list all the available services.

Regards,
/Nuwan

Answer (score 4):

If some one needs it:

```
Admin services deployed on this server:
1. ProvisioningAdminService, ProvisioningAdminService, https://localhost:8243/se
rvices/ProvisioningAdminService

2. SynapseApplicationAdmin, SynapseApplicationAdmin, https://localhost:8243/serv
ices/SynapseApplicationAdmin

3. CarbonAppUploader, CarbonAppUploader, https://localhost:8243/services/CarbonA
ppUploader

4. OperationAdmin, OperationAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/OperationAdmi
n

5. EventPublishService, EventPublishService, http://localhost:8280/services/Even
tPublishService

6. SequenceAdminService, SequenceAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/S
equenceAdminService

7. XKMSAdminService, XKMSAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/XKMSAdmin
Service

8. StatisticsAdmin, StatisticsAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/StatisticsA
dmin

9. LoggedUserInfoAdmin, LoggedUserInfoAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/Log
gedUserInfoAdmin

10. MediationStatisticsAdmin, MediationStatisticsAdmin, https://localhost:8243/s
ervices/MediationStatisticsAdmin

11. TopicManagerAdminService, TopicManagerAdminService, https://localhost:8243/s
ervices/TopicManagerAdminService

12. MessageProcessorAdminService, MessageProcessorAdminService, https://localhos
t:8243/services/MessageProcessorAdminService

13. ApplicationAdmin, ApplicationAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/Applicat
ionAdmin

14. ServiceGroupAdmin, ServiceGroupAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/Servic
eGroupAdmin

15. ClassMediatorAdmin, ClassMediatorAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/Clas
sMediatorAdmin

16. STSAdminService, STSAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/STSAdminSe
rvice

17. RegistryAdminService, RegistryAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/
RegistryAdminService

18. FileDownloadService, FileDownloadService, https://localhost:8243/services/Fi
leDownloadService

19. CachingAdminService, CachingAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/Ca
chingAdminService

20. MessageStoreAdminService, MessageStoreAdminService, https://localhost:8243/s
ervices/MessageStoreAdminService

21. RMAdminGlobal, RMAdminGlobal, https://localhost:8243/services/RMAdminGlobal

22. CSGAgentAdminService, CSGAgentAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/
CSGAgentAdminService

23. QpidAdminService, QpidAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/QpidAdmi
nService

24. LoginStatisticsAdmin, LoginStatisticsAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/
LoginStatisticsAdmin

25. CustomUIAdminService, CustomUIAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/
CustomUIAdminService

26. ReportingResourcesSupplier, ReportingResourcesSupplier, https://localhost:82
43/services/ReportingResourcesSupplier

27. RMAdminService, RMAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/RMAdminServi
ce

28. SearchAdminService, SearchAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/Sear
chAdminService

29. AuthenticationAdmin, AuthenticationAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/Au
thenticationAdmin

30. JMSTransportAdmin, JMSTransportAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/JMSTra
nsportAdmin

31. ThrottleAdminService, ThrottleAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/
ThrottleAdminService

32. TaskAdmin, TaskAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/TaskAdmin

33. ModuleAdminService, ModuleAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/Modu
leAdminService

34. MediationTracerService, MediationTracerService, https://localhost:8243/servi
ces/MediationTracerService

35. RestApiAdmin, RestApiAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/RestApiAdmin

36. LoggingAdmin, LoggingAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/LoggingAdmin
37. ExternalTryitService, ExternalTryitService, https://localhost:8243/services/
ExternalTryitService http://localhost:8280/services/ExternalTryitService

38. SecurityAdminService, SecurityAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/
SecurityAdminService

39. KeyStoreAdminService, KeyStoreAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/
KeyStoreAdminService

40. JrxmlFileUploader, JrxmlFileUploader, https://localhost:8243/services/JrxmlF
ileUploader

41. DiscoveryAdmin, DiscoveryAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/DiscoveryAdm
in

42. EndpointAdmin, EndpointAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/EndpointAdmin

43. ServerRolesManager, ServerRolesManager, https://localhost:8243/services/Serv
erRolesManager

44. ResourceAdminService, ResourceAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/
ResourceAdminService

45. FileUploadService, FileUploadService, https://localhost:8243/services/FileUp
loadService

46. DataSourceAdmin, DataSourceAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/DataSource
Admin

47. WSDLValidatorService, WSDLValidatorService, http://localhost:8280/services/W
SDLValidatorService https://localhost:8243/services/WSDLValidatorService

48. ConfigServiceAdmin, ConfigServiceAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/Conf
igServiceAdmin

49. CommandMediatorAdmin, CommandMediatorAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/
CommandMediatorAdmin

50. EventBrokerService, EventBrokerService, https://localhost:8243/services/Even
tBrokerService

51. TracerAdmin, TracerAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/TracerAdmin

52. TransportAdmin, TransportAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/TransportAdm
in

53. ProxyServiceAdmin, ProxyServiceAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/ProxyS
erviceAdmin

54. Java2WSDLService, Java2WSDLService, http://localhost:8280/services/Java2WSDL
Service https://localhost:8243/services/Java2WSDLService

55. InfoAdminService, InfoAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/InfoAdmi
nService

56. RepositoryAdminService, RepositoryAdminService, https://localhost:8243/servi
ces/RepositoryAdminService

57. PriorityMediationAdmin, PriorityMediationAdmin, https://localhost:8243/servi
ces/PriorityMediationAdmin

58. DeploymentSynchronizerAdmin, DeploymentSynchronizerAdmin, https://localhost:
8243/services/DeploymentSynchronizerAdmin

59. TemplateAdminService, TemplateAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/
TemplateAdminService

60. RelationAdminService, RelationAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/
RelationAdminService

61. DBReportingService, DBReportingService, https://localhost:8243/services/DBRe
portingService

62. ServerAdmin, ServerAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/ServerAdmin

63. ServiceAdmin, ServiceAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/ServiceAdmin

64. FlowsAdminService, FlowsAdminService, https://localhost:8243/services/FlowsA
dminService

65. UserAdmin, UserAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/UserAdmin

66. PropertiesAdminService, PropertiesAdminService, https://localhost:8243/servi
ces/PropertiesAdminService

67. LogViewer, LogViewer, https://localhost:8243/services/LogViewer

68. WSDL2CodeService, WSDL2CodeService, http://localhost:8280/services/WSDL2Code
Service https://localhost:8243/services/WSDL2CodeService

69. TransportStatisticsAdmin, TransportStatisticsAdmin, https://localhost:8243/s
ervices/TransportStatisticsAdmin

70. SynapseArtifactUploaderAdmin, SynapseArtifactUploaderAdmin, https://localhos
t:8243/services/SynapseArtifactUploaderAdmin

71. LocalEntryAdmin, LocalEntryAdmin, https://localhost:8243/services/LocalEntry
Admin

72. EndpointTemplateAdminService, EndpointTemplateAdminService, https://localhos
t:8243/services/EndpointTemplateAdminService
```

Comment: Thanks Nuvio, those are however different for each server. Seems only like 33 of them are common for al the servers. Regards, Ivo

Comment: oh yes, sorry this is for the ESB

Answer (score 3):

And if you want to retrieve the WSDLs of admin services of any Carbon server, go to "CARBON_HOME/repository/conf" directory and change the value of the "HideAdminServiceWSDLs" in "carbon.xml" file to "false" and restart the server. Then you can retrieve the WSDLs by browsing the service with "?wsdl" option.

```
For example,
https://localhost:8243/services/StatisticsAdmin?wsdl
```

Cheers,
Prabath

Comment: Thanks Prabath! Is there also somewhere documentation for what these services do, because for some you can figure out what they do only by the name, but there are also services that aren't so intuitive.

Comment: I'm afraid currently there's no such document available listing out what each of the Admin service does. However, if it is an option, you can of course browse the sources of the relevant components in the carbon public source repository and find more information on what each of the Admin Service is responsible for. This is not a difficult task as you can easily find the relevant component since almost of all the admin service names directly maps to the components they belong to.