# Where are WSO2 SOAP APIs / WSDL?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I've been reading everywhere including [here](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/XWiKoM1gYKACJzbS6Fij) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345934/xacml-java-api-recommendation) that WSO2 provided SOAP APIs for its services. My question is where are they? How can I locate them? For example, if there's a XACML API provided by WSO2, how can I find it.

What I understand about the WSO2 platform is that ESB, STS, DSS, IS are all services. To expose their functionalities, you have to write out standard XML, then import it into the WSO2 backend. After this, a WSDL is generated which can be used by a client. Am I right?
If not, then I have simple questions;

What is the endpoint or service url for all IS services?
What is the endpoint or service url for all ESB services?
What is the endpoint or service url for all STS services?
What is the endpoint or service url for all DSS services?

Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 uses Admin services and by default they are not exposed to outside and exposed over https.

You can view the list of services available by by referring this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368079/wso2-admin-service).

Another sample on using an Admin service is available [here](http://xacmlinfo.com/2012/06/13/pdp-pep-communication-wso2is/).

Sample developed to create proxy services using Proxy admin service is available [here](http://blog.shelan.org/2012/09/create-proxy-in-wso2-esb-using-admin.html)